# SQL case when set variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case-when

I am trying to set 2 declared variable with case when blocks

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @like bit,@dislike bit
if exists
( select * 
    ,@like = (CASE WHEN likeordislike = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)
    ,@dislike=(CASE WHEN likeordislike = 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)
  from likeordislike
)
```

But when I execute query throws errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Everything is ok? Couldn't understand

Comment: you can't set variables and return row results in the same query; it's one or the other.

Comment: Likeordislike is a table and a column in this table? Is there only one row? What are you trying to do? And could you show the table column information, how many rows are there?

Comment: I have a table named likeordislike which has  4 coulmns (comment_id,user,id,likeordislike,event_date),When an user click like I insert 1 into likeordislike column,if dislike 0 .I must select like or dislike status @RalfdeKleine

Comment: So you need to know if there is a record, if not insert it or else update the existing like/dislike?

Comment: if there is a record I will select other values and this variables as true/false..

Answer (score 1):

```
if (select count(*) from likeordislike where user = @user and comment_id = @comment_id) = 0
begin
  insert into likeordislike etc
end 
else
  update likeordislike etc
end
```